# Atualizar array sem ter que esperar outro usuário entrar

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat, real-time

Estou fazendo um chat com node.js e socket.io, estou com um erro na listagem dos valores de uma array, a array dos usuários. Coloquei uma `<ul></ul>` com um id e nada demais. segue as prints abaixo (o código da esquerda é o server e o da direita o client):
esse é o server:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    Msg.find().then(result => {
        socket.emit('output-messages', result)
    })

    /*User.find().then(result => {
        socket.emit('output-users', result)
    })*/

    socket.on('userConnected', (data) => {
        /*const userdb = new User({
            username: data.username
        });
        userdb.save().then(()=>{
            io.emit('displayUsers', data)
        }).catch(err =>{
            console.log("o erro foi: " + err)
        });*/

        io.emit('displayUsers', { users: users })


        users[socket.id] = data.username

        console.log(users)
    });

    socket.on('chat message', (data) => {
        const messagedb = new Msg({
            username: data.username,
            msgstring: data.msgstring
        });
        messagedb.save().then(()=>{
            io.emit('chat message', data)
        }).catch(err =>{
            console.log("o erro foi: " + err)
        });
        console.log(data)
    });


    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        try{
            delete users[socket.id]
            io.emit('disconnection', {users: users})
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        console.log(users)
    });
});
```

e esse é o client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chat da galera</title>

    <link 
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" 
        ntegrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"
    >
    <script 
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <style>
        body { margin: 0; padding-bottom: 3rem; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
  
        #form { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); padding: 0.25rem; position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 15%; right: 0; display: flex; height: 3rem; box-sizing: border-box; backdrop-filter: blur(10px); }
        #input { border: none; padding: 0 1rem; flex-grow: 1; border-radius: 2rem; margin: 0.25rem; }
        #input:focus { outline: none; }
        #form > button { background: #333; border: none; padding: 0 1rem; margin: 0.25rem; border-radius: 3px; outline: none; color: #fff; }
  
        #messages { list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin-left: 15%; }
        #messages > li { padding: 0.5rem 1rem; }
        #messages > li:nth-child(odd) { background: #efefef; }
        .namep{
            margin:0;
            padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
            color: rgb(10, 10, 10);
            background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        .namep2{
            margin:0;
            padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            font-size: 25px;
        }
        #usersOnline{
            position: fixed;
            width: 15%;
            height: 100%;
            backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        .usersH1{
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="usersOnline">
        <h1 class="usersH1" id="usersH1"></h1>
        <ul id="users"></ul>
    </div>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="form" action="">
      <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var name = window.prompt("Your username:")

        if(name == null){
            alert("Please insert a valid name!");
            location.reload();
        };


        var socket = io();

        var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
        var usersUl = document.getElementById('users');
        var usersTitle = document.getElementById('usersH1');
        var form = document.getElementById('form');
        var input = document.getElementById('input');


        form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if  (input.value) {
                socket.emit('chat message', {
                    username: name,
                    msgstring: input.value
                });
                input.value = '';
            }
        });

        socket.emit('userConnected', {username: name});
        socket.emit('disconnection', {username: name});

        socket.on('output-messages', data => {
            console.log(data)
            if (data.length) {
                data.forEach(message => {
                    appendUsers(message.username)
                    appendMessages(message.msgstring)
                });
            };
        });

        /*socket.on('output-users', data => {
            console.log(data)
            if (data.length) {
                data.forEach(message => {
                    appendUsersTab(message.username)
                });
            };
        });*/

        socket.on("displayUsers", function(data){
            let county = Object.keys(data.users).length

            usersTitle.textContent = 'Users (' + [county + 1] + ')'; 
            //usersUl.textContent = '' + data.users + ''; 
            usersUl.textContent = Object.values(data.users)
        });

        socket.on('disconnection', function(data) {

            console.log(data.users)
        });

        socket.on('chat message', function(obj) {
            let nameP = document.createElement('p');
            nameP.className = "namep"
            nameP.textContent = obj.username + ":";
            
            let item = document.createElement('li');
            item.textContent = obj.msgstring

            messages.appendChild(nameP);
            messages.appendChild(item);
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        });

        function appendUsersTab(message) {
            const html = `<p>${message}:</p>`
            usersUl.innerHTML += html
        }

        function appendUsers(message) {
            const html = `<p class="namep">${message}:</p>`
            messages.innerHTML += html
        }
        

        function appendMessages(message) {
            const html = `<p style=" padding:0.5rem 1rem; ">${message}</p>`
            messages.innerHTML += html
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

A array só atualiza quando um usuário entra, o que faz com que na `<ul>` dos usuários só apareça um user quando o outro entra, ex.: ali na imagem, só apareceu o usuário do joão quando o pedro entrou, e só apareceu o do pedro quando o josé entrou, e só vai aparecer o do josé se outro usuário entrar:

(o problema está na parte dos users)
[image: telas dos clients conectados]

Comment: mano, pq q td mundo vota negativo na minha pergunta, isso n vai me ajudar em nada, eu achava que o stackoverflow fosse para ajudar as pessoas que são iniciantes ou têm alguma dúvida, daí chega a pessoa e vota negativo achando que vai me ajudar em alguma coisa, além de não ajudar tira minha reputação. Que raiva, mano!!!!

Comment: _"eu achava que o stackoverflow fosse para ajudar as pessoas que são iniciantes ou têm alguma dúvida"_ - Não é de ajuda individual. E sobre o negativo, ele é quem faz o site ser útil, fazendo com que a infomação importante se destaque, e a problemática atrapalhe menos (veja o [Tour]). Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Comment: Postar um [mcve] no lugar do código original pode ajudar bastante também. Para mais detalhes tem a [help] e o [FAQ da Comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/70), espero que com estes links consiga aproveitar melhor o site, e ao mesmo tempo fornecer dúvidas que agreguem mais ao nosso repositório coletivo de conhecimento. Perguntas e respostas (mesmo que corretas) que só atendem ao caso específico de seu autor acabam fazendo o papel de helpdesk, e fogem completamente do objetivo do site (mesmo que resolvam o problema do autor, não cumprem a finalidade).

Comment: cara, ainda n entendi esse site, man, me deram downvote e não me ajudou em nada, mas obrigado pela compreensão.

Comment: Depois dê uma lidinha com calma nos links passados, acho que aí entende com o tempo, e pega o jeitão da coisa. Normal no começo ter alguma fricção, bastante usuário tem (e acho que o site é divulgado de uma maneira errada). Depois que a pessoa entende o objetivo verdadeiro do site (que é um repositório de conhecimento onde cada postagem pode ajudar outras pessoas, e como fazer isso), fica mais fácil (muitos passaram por isso e depois se entrosaram). Como comentei, negativo é só classificação, não se preocupe. Não é pessoal (não é igual like, de rede social, é só classificação técnica).

Comment: eu já vi teu usuário em uma votação para moderadores, mt massa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está aqui:

```js
io.emit('displayUsers', { users: users })
users[socket.id] = data.username
```

Quando um usuário entra, você transmite a lista de usuários para todos *antes* de inserir o novo usuário.

O que tá acontecendo é o seguinte:

1. `users` inicialmente vazia
2. Pedro entra
3. É transmitida a `users` (vazia) para todos
4. Pedro é inserido na `users`
5. João entra
6. É transmitida a `users` (contendo Pedro) para todos
7. João é inserido na `users`
8. José entra
9. É transmitida a `users` (contendo Pedro e João) para todos
10. José é inserido na `users`

E é assim que chegamos na situação descrita na última imagem. Basta atualizar a lista *antes* de transmiti-la:

```js
users[socket.id] = data.username
io.emit('displayUsers', { users: users })
```

Dessa maneira, quando um usuário novo entra, todos receberão uma versão da users que inclui o usuário que acabou de entrar.

P.S.: Sobre os downvotes na sua pergunta, também achei desnecessário. Espero que você tenha experiências melhores por aqui futuramente!

P.P.S.: Só uma dica... tome *muito* cuidado ao inserir conteúdo digitado por usuários diretamente no HTML. Seu handler para mensagens novas cuida disso usando o `textContent`, mas a `appendMessages` insere diretamente, sem filtrar, e isso é perigoso.

Comment: OBRIGADO, PELO AMOR DE DEUS MANO, DEUS TE ABENÇOE